# Finding numbers whose digits sum to a prime

Tags: algorithm

I was trying to solve this problem on SPOJ, in which I have to find how many numbers are there in a range whose digits sum up to a prime. This range can be very big, (upper bound of 10^8 is given). The naive solution timed out, I just looped over the entire range and checked the required condition. I cant seem find a pattern or a formula too. Could someone please give a direction to proceed in??

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 5):

Here are some tips:

- try to write a function that finds how many numbers in a given range have a given sum of the digits. Easiest way to implement this is to write a function that returns the number of numbers with a given sum of digits up to a given value a(call this f(sum,a)) and then the number of such numbers in the range a to b will be f(sum,b) - f(sum, a - 1)
- Pay attention that the sum of the digits itself will not be too high - up to 8 * 9 < 100 so the number of prime sums to check is really small

Hope this helps.

Comment: the range is `[1,72]` [for 99999999]. Other then that - great solution. +1

Comment: @amit the upper bound is 10^8 so in fact the range is [1,72] as I state in my answer. I just indicate that this is less then 100 so no problem to iterate over all the primes in that range.

Comment: I was referring to former version of your answer, which stated `18*9 < 200` numbers, and wanted to give a stricter bound.

Comment: How would you implement `f`? That seems to be the most difficult part here, if looking for a solution that doesn't loop over every possible number.

Comment: Easiest way is to split problem even further - find the number of numbers x that have a given number of digits d and sum of these digits equal to sum. For each such problems I suggest a dp approach where the dp is two dimensional - one dimensions is for the sum left and the second is for the number of digits left. So now you have to compute g(d, sum, a). I can provide code that will solve the problem but the idea in SPOJ is to make the user come up with the solution on his own.

Comment: Could the downvoter provide feedback on what is wrong in my answer so that I can improve it?

Comment: @izomorphius I was thinking about that solution as well, it is only 18 primes to check after all. But just slightly more complicated. Depends on the time controls.

Comment: @izomorphius. Thanks for the input. I will try to work on it and get back.

Answer (score 1):

I (seriously) doubt whether this 'opposite' approach will be any faster than @izomorphius's suggestion, but it might prompt some thoughts about improving the performance of your program:

1) Get the list of primes in the range 2..71 (you can omit 1 and 72 from any consideration since neither is prime).

2) Enumerate the integer partitions of each of the prime numbers in the list.  Here's some [Python code](http://homepages.ed.ac.uk/jkellehe/partitions.php).  You'd want to modify this so as not to generate partitions which were invalid, such as those containing numbers larger than 9.

3) For each of those partitions, pad out with 0s to make a set of 8 digits, then enumerate all the permutations of the padded set.

Now you have the list of numbers you require.

Answer (score 0):

Generate the primes using the sieve of Eratosthenes up to the maximum sum (9 + 9...). Put them in a Hash table. Then you could likely loop quickly through 10^8 numbers and add up their sums. There might be more efficient methods, but this should be quick enough.

Comment: I doubt it will have much affect, since the range of prime numbers needed is `[1,72]`

Comment: @amit 10^7 took 17 seconds, so I guess 10^8 will take 10x that. It's not the best way obviously. But if the requirements aren't under 1 minute, it's very few lines of code and easily understood.

Comment: I've ran it on 10^8, took 3:11.

Comment: @YuriyFaktorovich in computer programming competitions the usual time limit is 1 second, but for this problem it might be even more strict. I believe the best solution will finish in way less then 0.1 seconds for the maximum test case.

Comment: @izomorphius If it is, then I stand corrected. But he didn't specify it in the question.

Comment: @YuriyFaktorovich The time limit is one second.